# Quickbooks 2005 Web Integration

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks

A customer of ours has Quickbooks 2005 and is looking to have their web data (orders, customers, tax) sent as it is collected from the web in a format that can be imported into Quickbooks 2005 Pro.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  If so, what was your experience, and what component/method would you recommend for importing this data into Quickbooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [QuickBooks Web Connector](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/).

There is a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331/integrating-quickbooks-with-your-e-commerce-site

Answer (score 3):

The QuickBooks Web Connector is almost certainly the only way to go for integrating websites with QuickBooks.

Here is a wiki with some additional information: 
http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks

You'll also want to see the QuickBooks OSR: 
http://developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-Current/Common/newOSR/index.html

And the QuickBooks SDK: 
http://developer.intuit.com/

PHP specific framework: 
http://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=9164